# hover give whole li a background color

Tags: html, css

Im trying to give a `li` a `background-color`, everything i tried it didn't give the whole `li` the color it just give it from where the text starts.

How do i make it give a `background-color` to the whole `li`

JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/r2wL2pqj/

CODE

HTML

```
                <ul class="items-list">
                    <li class="nickname-list">
                        <span class="nickname">The Nickname</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="home-list">
                        <span class="home">Home</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="search-list">
                        <span class="search-friend">Search friends</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

STYLE

```
ul.items-list li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(58, 87, 149, 0.66);
    cursor: pointer;

    border-radius: 5px;
}
.items{
    float:right;
}
ul.items-list {
    display: -webkit-box;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.items-list li {
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.items-list li:after {
    color: #385490;
    content: "|";   
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.nickname, .home,.search-friend {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 10px;
}
```

Also is this the right way for doing this, am I on the right track ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the margin, use padding instead:

```
.items-list li {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I get a full background, the gap between is your margin, try changing your margin to a padding if you want the whole gap between the pipes to change.

```
.items-list li {
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r2wL2pqj/1/